# Compare two tables in HIVE

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, nosql

I have 3 tables in hive:

- Control_table, with known data
- New_table, with data to check
- Result_table, table where records with different values in new_table then control_table are inserted to

All three tables have same column names (which I won't actually present for security reasons) and number of columns and those are:

```
c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7
```

Where c1 is acting as primary key.

Now I need to put together SQL query for HIVE to compare two tables (control_table with new_table) and rows which have different values to be moved into result table. Now result table have same number of columns as new_table or control_table. If possible I would like to populate only columns which are actually different.

So example of this would be:

```
Control_table:  c1  | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | c6 | c7 |

With a values:  11  | 22 | 33 | 44 | 55 | 66 | 77 |
```

---

```
New_table:   c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | c6 | c7 |

With values: 11 | 21 | 33 | 44 | 54 | 66 | 87 |
```

---

Compare them and result insert into result_table, so result table would look like this:

```
Result_table:  c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | c6 | c7 |

With values:   11 | 21 | -- | -- | 54 | -- | 87 |
```

So only columns with the actual difference in value would be populated.

Now I am rubbish in the SQL, I tried several approaches and tried to ask question here, but got never good answer, here is link to my previous answer which has also example of the sql:

[How to compare two tables and return rows with difference with HIVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379409/how-to-compare-two-tables-and-return-rows-with-difference-with-hive)

P.S.: It might be that this is not possible, I'm not sure, as I have no previous experiences with NoSQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify bellow for your purpose:

```
SELECT nt.c1,
       CASE WHEN ct.c2 <> nt.c2 THEN '--' ELSE  nt.c2 END,
       CASE WHEN ct.c3 <> nt.c2 THEN '--' ELSE  nt.c3 END
FROM 
New_table nt
JOIN Control_table ct ON nt.c1 = ct.c1
WHERE
ct.c2 <> nt.c2 OR ct.c3 <> nt.c3
```

Comment: Although you have mentioned to modify your code, still then and else values needs to be swapped to match the answer to the original question.

Comment: @www- why you have added where clause in join statement? WHERE
ct.c2 <> nt.c2 OR ct.c3 <> nt.c3... can we get the desired result without having this where stament

Comment: @vikrantrana I have added it just for the clarity, if you would like to have in JOIN please do so.

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from Control_table    
full outer join New_table     
on Control_table.c1=New_table.c1     
where Control_table.c1 is null  or  New_table.c1 is null;
```

This would fetch records if any of the record mismatches from both tables. And you can do you table data validation. If you want to store it into other table.
create a managed table with:

```
CREATE TABLE RESULT_TABLE AS SELECT * FROM Control_table;
```

and load the result into this result table as:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE RESULT_TABLE     
select * from Control_table full outer join New_table on     
Control_table.c1=New_table.c1    
 where Control_table.c1 is null    
or  New_table.c1 is null;
```